# Need help in creating a simple ml model using keras

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, tf.keras

i am trying to create model to predict spending score of this ( 200 rows- i am giving first few )
I have used one hot encoding , then use minmaxscalar in a for loop to scale each column separately, then
I created a model using keras andMy loss function is reducing rapidly but accuracy so low
also if i add more layer then I can have accuracy but it fails miserably in test data.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wI1Um.png)

here is my code:

```
df=df.drop('CustomerID',axis=1)
df.head()
ohe=preprocessing.OneHotEncoder()
feature_array=ohe.fit_transform(df[['Genre']]).toarray()
feature_labels=np.array(ohe.categories_).ravel()

features=pd.DataFrame(feature_array,columns=feature_labels)
df=pd.concat([df,features],axis=1)
df=df.drop('Genre',axis=1) 

df=df[['Male','Female','Age','Annual Income (k$)','Spending Score (1-100)']]
df.head()

scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()

for col in df.columns:
    if col != 'Spending Score (1-100)':
        df[col] = scaler.fit_transform(df[[col]])

df.head()

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(df.drop('Spending Score (1-100)',axis=1),df['Spending Score (1-100)'],test_size=0.2)

model=keras.Sequential([
  keras.layers.Dense(50,input_shape=(4,),activation='relu'),
  keras.layers.Dense(75,activation='relu'),
  keras.layers.Dense(100,activation='sigmoid')

])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
                                    
model.fit(x_train,y_train,epochs=1000,batch_size=10)
```

I was expecting good accuracy but its so low, i even scaled the data :C

Answer (score 0):

Meh, actually in this case you are more in a regression problem than a classification.
But you still want to solve it like a classification problem, first, you should use softmax instead of sigmoid in the last layer.
Second, have you used one hot encoding for the output variable? If you have then use categorical_crossentropy instead of sparse_categorical_crossentropy, if you haven't just remain sparse_categorical_crossentropy.

Comment: I tried it no changes

Comment: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1011447733393043628/1090311031160569906/Temporary.ipynb

Comment: ok, I see the mistake now. Do you what do treat that as a classification problem? In this case you can do this: 1º use sparse_categorical_crossentropy. 2º don't do minmax to the column Spending Score (1-100), just leave it with integers.  3º use softmax activation in your last later with 100 neurons.

Comment: I did as you asked but accuracy is still low, here is the csv file along with the updated code
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/401597942756278294/1090512840818958386/Mall_cust.ipynb

https://anonfiles.com/n49eB4hazf/Mall_Customers_csv

Comment: I also tried linear regression but the predictions are wrong even if the loss if low

Comment: I see in your notebbok y_test is still float, it should be integers.

Comment: With regression will be better for this case.

Comment: But even with regression the loss is still very much. :C

Comment: I see in your csv, you have very few data. I can't make a good model with so few data.

Comment: Something you can do is to make less clases for your classification problem. For example from 1-10=class1, 11-20=class2 and so on. It will make your problem less demanding, and easier to predict.

Comment: ok fine, so my code is correct?

Comment: The last notebook is fine